# Conditional render Navigation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, datocms

Hi I need conditional render my navigation. I use Gatsby and GraphQl. I have Navigation Component and depends on route in which it is I need render different Navigation. The problem is I can not make conditional useStateStatic hook. I've made two diffrent Navigation in my source it is DatoCMS,but I can not query for it.

```
const Navigation = () => {
  const pathName = window.location.pathname;
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      {
        datoCmsNavigation(sectionId: { eq: "navigation" }) {
          sectionId
          logo {
            url
            alt
          }
          menuItem {
            id
            name
            href
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );

  const {
    datoCmsNavigation: { sectionId, logo, menuItem },
  } = data;

  return (
    <NavBar id={sectionId}>
      <NavBarLogoWrapper>
        <a href="/">
          <img src={logo.url} alt={logo.test} />
        </a>
      </NavBarLogoWrapper>

      <NavBarList>
        {menuItem.map((item, index) => (
          <NavBarItem key={index}>
            <a href={item.href}> {item.name.toLowerCase()}</a>
          </NavBarItem>
        ))}
      </NavBarList>
    </NavBar>
  );
};
```

Here is my Navigation component. Does anyone has Idea how can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will fail in gatsby build since [`window` (and other global objects) are not available during the SSR](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/). You don't need a useState hook in your scenario, you just need to know which page is actually the user seeing.

Top-level components (pages) in Gatsby own the [`location` property](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/), which allows you to know a bunch of data, including the current page. You can pass that data to your `Navigation` component in order to make your comparison. For example:

```
const Blog = ({location, someOtherDestructuredProps}) => {

   return <section>
     <Navigation currentPage={location.pathname}/>
     <OtherComponent />
   </section>
}
```

Then, in your Navigation component:

```
const Navigation = ({currentPage ="/"}) => {
  const pathName = window.location.pathname;
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      {
        datoCmsNavigation(sectionId: { eq: "navigation" }) {
          sectionId
          logo {
            url
            alt
          }
          menuItem {
            id
            name
            href
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );

  const {
    datoCmsNavigation: { sectionId, logo, menuItem },
  } = data;

  return (
    <NavBar id={sectionId}>
      <NavBarLogoWrapper>
        <a href="/">
          <img src={logo.url} alt={logo.test} />
        </a>
      </NavBarLogoWrapper>

      <NavBarList>
        {menuItem.map((item, index) => {
         
         if(currentPage == '/blog') return <DifferentNavBar />
         return <NavBarItem key={index}>
            <a href={item.href}> {item.name.toLowerCase()}</a>
          </NavBarItem>
        })}
      </NavBarList>
    </NavBar>
  );
};
```

Among minor changes, the important part is to set a default value for the `currentPage` (in case it's missing) and the change of the `map` loop in order to return different navigation bars. Of course, tweak it to adapt it to your needs and requeriments.